# uncaught TypeError innerHTML of null in xhttp.onreadystatechange setInterval function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I am trying to update several variables on a web page using `JSON`.
Some but not all of the variables are updated, and I get an

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

on different variables at different times.

Most of what I've read online about these problems is that the script has to run after the `HTML` is loaded.  But isn't that the case when using `xhttp` `setInterval` functions?

The page with the HTML and the scripts follow.

The `javascript` to parse the `JSON` object treats each element the same way but the outcome is not consistent.  The first 3 elements get updated every time.  The rest of them only one or two gets updated. In addition at least one of them - it varies, sometimes it's HUM_ST, sometimes FAN_ST and sometimes COOL_ST -  generates the ucaught error described above.  The buttons are in forms, so perhaps that's part of it.
They are also buttons not just variables. In the actual file, the script is at the end, after the  marker.

```js
<script>
setInterval(function() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("OpenCLOSE").innerHTML = jsonResponse.OPN;
      document.getElementById("A0Read").innerHTML = jsonResponse.A0R;
      document.getElementById("RChanRel").innerHTML = jsonResponse.RCH;
      document.getElementById("humMode").innerHTML = jsonResponse.HUM;
      document.getElementById("htMode").innerHTML = jsonResponse.HT;
      document.getElementById("cmode").innerHTML = jsonResponse.CL;
      document.getElementById("eMode").innerHTML = jsonResponse.EX;
      document.getElementById("fMode").innerHTML = jsonResponse.FAN;
      document.getElementById("lMode").innerHTML = jsonResponse.LED;
      console.log(jsonResponse.FAN, jsonResponse.HUM);
      alert(jsonResponse.FAN, jsonResponse.HUM);
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/SystemUpdate", true);
  xhttp.send();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>System</h1>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="index.html">Main</a>
  <a href="LogData.html">Log</a>
  <a href="System.html">System</a>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <p>
      <form action="/HumBtn" method="get">
        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
            <input type="radio" name="HumBtn" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1">Hum On<span 
             class="checkmark"></span></label>

        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
            <input type="radio" name="HumBtn" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="0">Hum Off<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
      </form>
    </p>
    <p><span id="humMode">%HUM_ST%</span></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <form action="/HeatBtn" method="get">
        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
                <input type="radio" name="HeatBtn" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="1">Heat On<span 
                 class="checkmark"></span></label>

        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
                <input type="radio" name="HeatBtn" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="0">Heat Off<span 
             class="checkmark"></span></label>
      </form>
    </p>
    <p><span id="htMode">%HEAT_ST%</span></p>

  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <form action="/CoolBtn" method="get">
        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
                <input type="radio" name="CoolBtn" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="1">Cool On<span 
                 class="checkmark"></span></label>

        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
                 <input type="radio"  name="CoolBtn" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="0">Cool Off<span 
               class="checkmark"></span></label>
      </form>
    </p>
    <p><span id="cMode">%COOL_ST%</span></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <form action="/ExtBtn" method="get">
        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
                <input type="radio"  name="ExtBtn"  onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1">Ext On<span 
                class="checkmark"></span></label>

        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
                 <input type="radio"  name="ExtBtn"  onclick="this.form.submit();" value="0">Ext Off<span 
            class="checkmark"></span></label>
      </form>
    </p>
    <p><span id="eMode">%EXT_ST%</span></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <form action="/FanBtn" method="get">
        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
                <input type="radio"  name="FanBtn"  onclick="this.form.submit();"  value="1">Fan On<span 
             class="checkmark"></span></label>

        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
                 <input type="radio"  name="FanBtn"  onclick="this.form.submit();" value="0">Fan Off<span 
             class="checkmark"></span></label>
      </form>
    </p>
    <p><span id="fMode">%FAN_ST%</span></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <form action="/LEDBtn" method="get">
        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
                <input type="radio"  name="LEDBtn"  onclick="this.form.submit();" value="1">LED On<span 
                class="checkmark"></span></label>

        <label class="radio"><span class="radio__input">
                 <input type="radio"  name="LEDBtn"  onclick="this.form.submit();" value="0">LED Off<span 
            class="checkmark"></span></label>
      </form>
    </p>
    <p><span id="lMode">%LED_ST%</span></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><a href="More.html">SensorAdj</a></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Cover Status</p>
    <p><span id="OpenCLOSE">%CoverStatus%</span></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>A0Read</p>
    <p><span id="A0Read">%A0Read%</span></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Relay Channel Status</p>
    <p><span id="RChanRel">%RChanRel%</span></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please replace all templating with HTML and make a [mcve]

Comment: You have jQuery. Use it. Use $.ajax or $.get and use $("#id").html(...) instead of document.getElementById, or don't use jQuery at all

Comment: Also DRY (don't repeat yourself) and make a function that calculates the mum and such and call it when needed

Comment: Also please read about the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

`$('[name="HumBtn"]').val( hummode == "OFF" ? "0" : "1")` or even just 

`$('[name="HumBtn"]').val(hummode == "OFF");`